# Fee for sending 4.3 ether with gasprice set to 200000

Tags: fees

I'm about to buy some ICO and I want to maximize my purchase. What is the fee
on 4.3eth with the gasprice set to 200000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really does depend on the gwei, network etc.

But go have a look at http://ethgasstation.info/

You can change it up and see what it has been as an average for the last 1500 blocks.

Otherwise have a look at the contract address in etherscan.io to see what others are paying...

Answer (score 0):

The fee for transferring ether is independent of the amount transferred. Furthermore, the gas price is often specified in the units of gwei per gas (one gwei is a billionth of an ether). A standard value transfer transaction (sending ether from one account to another) costs 21000 gas. You can multiply your gas price by your transaction cost in gas to get your transaction cost in ether.

A more [typical gas price](http://ethgasstation.info) on the main net is around 20 gwei/gas which works out to 20 x 21000 = 420000 billionths of an ether or 0.42 thousandths of an ether. At a price of $300USD per ether, that's $300 USD/ETH x (0.42/1000) ETH ≈ 12.6¢ ($0.126).